# connect(), accept() and select() happening sequence order

Tags: c, tcp

I am a newbie in C. 
 
 I just noticed that the `connect()` function on the client side can return as long as the TCP three-way hand-shake is finished. I mean `connect()` can even return before the `accept()` on the server side is called (correct me if I am wrong). 
 
 Based on this knowledge, my question is that when I call `select()` afterwards on the client side, and watch the file descriptor to wait for it to be writeable, when `select()` successfully returns, that means the server side has already called `accept()` and now I can safely write to the server side, right? Many thanks for your time.

```
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);

flags |= O_NONBLOCK;

fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);

if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)saptr, salen) < 0)
{
    if (errno != EINPROGRESS)
        /* error_return */
}

fd_set set;
FD_ZERO (&set);

FD_SET (fd, &set);

select (FD_SETSIZE, NULL, &set, NULL, &timeout)
/* Here, if select returns 1, that means accept() is already called 
   on the server side, and now I can safely write to the server, right? */
```

Comment: 'I mean connect() can even return before the accept() on the server side is called' - sure, yes.

Answer (score 3):

> when select() successfully returns, that means the server side has already called accept()

No, not necessarily.  `connect()` returns when the connection attempt is complete, having either succeeded or failed.  On the remote side, this is handled by the network stack, outside the context of any application.  The subsequent `accept()` itself produces no additional communication.

> and now I can safely write to the server side, right?

There are all kinds of things you could mean by "safely", but if you mean that the local side can write at least one byte without blocking then yes, `select()` promises you that.  Whatever you successfully write will be sent over the wire to the remote side.  It may be buffered there for a time, depending on the behavior of the software on the remote end.  Whether that software has yet `accept()`ed the connection or not is not directly relevant to that question.

**Update:** note also that the network stack maintains a per-socket queue of established connections that have not yet been `accept()`ed (its backlog).  This queuing behavior is one reason why a server might not `accept()` connections immediately after they are established, especially under heavy load.

Comment: Good answer. Might consider an extra note on `listen()`'s backlog.

Comment: @John Bollinger Thanks for your answer. I just did a small experiment to test. Yes, the return of  `select` does not necessarily mean the server side has already called `accept`.

Answer (score -1):

> 'I mean connect() can even return before the accept() on the server
>   side is called'

Yes, it can, and does.

> when I call select() afterwards on the client side, and watch the file
>   descriptor to wait for it to be writeable, when select() successfully
>   returns, that means the server side has already called accept() and
>   now I can safely write to the server side, right?

Sure.  Write away:)